# Facebook Getting status with pagination limit

Tags: android, facebook, api

I am developing a iphone/android app that needs to show client daily fb status messages into app. This happens with authentication and it works fine(Connected with PHP FB SDK API) and now I need to show all the status messages from that user wall(now its just giving only 20 statues by default).

I am able to see previous/next page URL Links

```
[previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/statuses?date_format=U&limit=25&since=1328969556&__paging_token=10150777962697519&__previous=1

[next] => https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/statuses?date_format=U&limit=25&until=1264999321&__paging_token=327111876040
```

But not sure how to call this to get next set of status message list.

When I call the URL directly it gives me this error message in json format

> An access token is required to request this resource.

So I added access token(that was returned by FB) to this URL as like

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/statuses?date_format=U&limit=25&until=1264999321&__paging_token=327111876040&access_token=returned_access_token_string

And it returns empty data json but that user have more than 1000 statues on his wall. How can i access the fb status with limit by limit.